# SEC Form D - Are Founders Investors?

Tags: united-states, securities, sec

**Main Question:**
Are Founders considered "investors" for purposed of filing the SEC's [Form D](https://www.sec.gov/about/forms/formd.pdf)?

**Context:**
I am starting a corporation with 2 others. We have set up Restricted Stock Purchase Agreement where each of us are paying a nominal fee of $30 in total for each founder to purchase the shares with a vesting schedule.

**Follow up questions**

1. On Form D item 9, "Type(s) of Securities Offered", would this be "Security to be Acquired Upon Exercise of Option, Warrant or Other Right to Acquire Security"?
2. For item 13 and 14, would I put $90 because that's the total money the company will acquire with this transaction? Additionally would I put 3 investors because we 3 founders are buying the shares?

Comment: hmmm, my thought is that this is a contract regarding the formation of a corporation and hence more suited for legal consideration.

Comment: Why would you ever bother to do Reg D paperwork in a $90 capital company owned by active founding members?